# Search method not pulling data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I just created a search method in my model. However, it seems to partially work. Essentially, if someone were to put a name of a hero in the search field it should pull all the "reports" associated to the Hero and all the relevent data from the index.

Right now, I search for "Thor" let's say, I have 3 reports in the list of 4 reports that are associated to him. The others are associated to other another hero. It goes through the motions and then brings me to the index page but does not display any errors or reports on the page/table. Just an empty screen. Like so.

[image]

[image]

Report Model

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
   validates :subject, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 100 }
   validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 300 }

   belongs_to :user
   
   has_many :report_heros
   has_many :heros, through: :report_heros

   has_many :report_villains
   has_many :villains, through: :report_villains

    def self.search(search)
        if search
            hero = Hero.find_by(hero_name: search)
                if hero
                    self.where(hero_id: hero.id)
                else
                    Report.all
                end
        else
            Report.all
        end
    end
    
end
```

Report Index

```
<div class="container">
   <h1 class="row justify-content-center">Reports</h1>
   <h3> Search for a Hero related Reports</h3>
   <%= form_tag reports_path, :method => "get" do %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:search, params[:search])%>
      <%= submit_tag("Search", :name => nil) %>
   <% end %>

   <table class="table table-bordered bg-light">
      <thead bgcolor="#959595">
         <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Ticket Number</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Subject</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Created By</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Hero Involved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Villain Involved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Edit</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Delete</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <% @reports.each do |report|%>
         <tr>
         <% if report.user == current_user || current_user.admin? %>
            <td class="text-center"><%= link_to report.id, report_path(report) %></td>
            <td><%= report.subject %></td>
            <td><%= link_to report.user.email, report_path(report) %></td>
            <% report.heros.each do |hero|%>
            <td class="text-center"><%= link_to hero.hero_name, report_hero_path(report.id, hero.id) %></td>
            <% end %>
            <% report.villains.each do |villain|%>
            <td class="text-center"><%= link_to villain.villain_name, report_villain_path(report.id, villain.id) %></td>
            <% end %>
            <td class="text-center"><%= link_to "Edit Report", edit_report_path(report) %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><%= link_to "Delete Report", report_path(report), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></td>
            <% end %>
         </tr>
         <% end %>
      </tbody>
   </table>

   <%= link_to 'New Report', new_report_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

Reports Controller

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :require_login
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
    before_action :set_report, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
    
    def index
        @reports = Report.all
        @reports = Report.search(params[:search])
    end
    
    def show
    end
    
    def new
        @report = current_user.reports.new
    end
    
    def create
        @report = current_user.reports.build(report_params)
        if @report.save
            flash[:notice] = "Report was created successfully."
            redirect_to @report
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
    
    def update
        if @report.update(report_params)
            flash[:notice] = "Report updated successfully"
            redirect_to @report
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
    
    def edit
    end
    
    def destroy
        @report.destroy
        redirect_to reports_path
    end
    
    private
    
    def set_report
        @report = Report.find(params[:id])
    end
    
    def report_params
        params.require(:report).permit(:subject, :description, :hero_ids, :villain_ids, :search)
    end

    def require_login
        unless user_signed_in?
          flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access this section"
          redirect_to root_path
        end
    end

    def require_same_user
        if current_user != @report.user && !current_user.admin?
          flash[:alert] = "You can only edit or delete your own article"
          redirect_to @report
        end
    end
end
```

This is what is being queried-

```
Started GET "/reports?search=Thor" for ::1 at 2020-09-04 20:58:13 -0500
Processing by ReportsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"search"=>"Thor"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:57:in `require_login'
  Hero Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "heros".* FROM "heros" WHERE "heros"."hero_name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["hero_name", "Thor"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/report.rb:15:in `search'
  Rendering reports/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Report Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."hero_id" = ?  [["hero_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/reports/index.html.erb:22
  Rendered reports/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.1ms | Allocations: 793)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 435)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 17)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 5)
Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 8.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 7637)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first inclination is to tell you to specify the class name on your associations. For example:

```rb
has_many :report_heros, class_name: 'Report::Hero'
has_many :heros, through: :report_heros
```

Although this doesn't make a lot of general sense to me, because your code above is querying a Hero class. So it seems to me that the association here should just be `has_many :heroes, class_name: 'Hero'` unless you do indeed have a Report::Hero model. Additionally, you may need to specify a `source` in your has_many-through statement. Side note, the plural of 'hero' is 'heroes', so your association is also misspelled.

Next, Report and Hero are different object types, and your search method is sometimes returning Hero objects and sometimes returning Report objects. But your code appears to be expecting Report objects. So it's probably hitting `report.user == current_user || current_user.admin?` and evaluating to false if `user` doesn't exist on the Hero model (or if it's blank); this could easily explain why everything is blank.

My next recommendation is to make some improvements to your search class method, both to its logic (so it always returns a report) and to clean up and simplify your syntax. You might write something like this:

```rb
def self.search(name)
  # Sanitize your input
  name = name.strip
  
  # This assumes the attribute on your Hero model is 'name'
  # Having the name 'hero_name' as a name on the Hero model is redundant
  if name.present?
    # Fetch all *Report* objects where the an associated Hero's name 
    # matches the name passed to the method as an argument
    reports = Report.joins(:heroes).where(heroes: { name: name }).presence 
    # You may need to replace 'joins' with 'includes'
  end

  # Calling [].presence returns nil, so using memoization here means 
  # Report.all is only queried if a name was present but the query returned []
  reports ||= Report.all
end
```

My last thought would be that your database is for some reason not configured for case-insensitive matching, but really I think the most likely issue is that your search method is returning two entirely different data types (Hero and Report). If this isn't the issue, please provide some information about the associated models and their schemas.

Comment: Thanks Allison, that worked. The only part of the code I don't quite get is Report.joins(:heroes). I looked up the reference material from https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins but still had some trouble understanding. Do you happen to have any good references? FYI I also knew Heroes was misspelled lol. The generator created it that way and I noticed it late in the development and left it as is. I accounted for that in most of the app.

Comment: Also, thank you for taking the time for the lengthy response and helping me understand what was going on.

Comment: @MarrixRed NW, it's confusing stuff. That rails query is saying fetch all reports that have a record associated via the heroes association where the name attribute in the heroes table is equal to the name argument received by the search method. It evaluates in SQL to something like `SELECT * FROM reports INNER JOIN heroes ON reports.hero_id = heroes.id WHERE heroes.name = 'the name argument';` I found this helpful when I was first learning association filtering in rails queries: https://scoutapm.com/blog/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where

Comment: Also if the rails model generator generates names incorrectly, you can still modify whatever you want as long as you make it consistent (Rails relies on consistency for rails magic). I will usually look at the generated files and update names and file paths to have the correct grammar. This should be done _before_ applying the migration (e.g., db:migrate).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this part isn't working (otherwise all of the reports should be returned):

```
hero = Hero.find_by(hero_name: search)
  if hero
    self.where(hero_id: hero)
```

Does it work if you change it to:

```
self.where(hero_id: hero.id)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not - still the same thing. I updated the code and provided the results from the rails s